# Return table measures in DAX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, powerbi, dax

How I can use created measures for DAX table? For columns or calculated columns it works (count is only for example):

```
EVALUATE
row("test", count(FactSales[Sales]))
```

but for measure I get (in DAX Studio):

```
EVALUATE
row("test", count(FactSales[Sales2]))
```

> Column 'Sales2' in table 'FactSales' cannot be found or may not be used
>   in this expression.

The column must exist because I dragged and dropped it from left Dax Studio panel. This table came from Power BI model and measure works there.

Comment: `COUNT` is expecting a column, and a measure is not a column.. You could try `COUNTX` instead

Comment: It should work, try creating a measure for count `MyMeasure = count(FactSales[Sales2])` then use `row("test", [MyMeasure] )`. Is Sales2 a calculated column?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Sales2 is a measure.

Answer (score 1):

COUNT() expects a column. From your reply above, it sounds like [Sales2] is a measure. You cannot count a measure.

If you want to return the value of [Sales2], take the COUNT() away and just leave:

```
EVALUATE
ROW ( "test", [Sales2] )
```